# Как сделать приветственное сообщение в беседе телеграм aiogram python

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Нужно сделать скрытое приветственное сообщение. Я вступил в беседу и увидел сообщение от бота лично мне, остальные участники его не получили. Поискал в интернете информацию, но так и не нашел именно скрытого сообщения. [image: последнее сообщение вижу только я]

Answer (score 2):

Сообщение в телеграмме не может быть показано только для конкретного человека в общей беседе. Если ты про то, что он обратился к тебе, то это можно сделать так:

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["new_chat_members"])
async def on_user_joined(message: types.Message):  

await message.delete()

await message.answer("[{} {}](tg://user?id={}),  Добро пожаловать в чат "
                     .format(message.from_user.first_name, message.from_user.last_name, message.from_user.id),
                     disable_web_page_preview=True,
                     parse_mode="Markdown")
```